# Use existing SQL Server database to create website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have an existing SQL Server database and I want to make a site that will work with it. I have worked previsouly with RoR and ASP NET MVC 3 but in these technologies the databases seem to be built-in in application itself. Given my limitation (using an existing database) what's the best technology to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not clear on what problem you have with RoR nor ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I have to agree with pst... this is a rather broad 'question'.  We use C# with ASP.NET 4.0 for most of our new websites.  Then we use a WCF data layer that talks to our SQL database and we pass custom objects from WCF to the website to work with.  Abstracting your site and data layer provides many benefits for us but that all depends on the scope of your project.  WCF also allows you quite a bit of flexibility when it comes to how you develop the front end.  While we are consuming it from ASP.NET websites in some areas, other places consume it using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This is an opinion of course

The first thing you need is freetds,

[freetds.org](http://freetds.org)

Then you need to install the SQLServer Adapter

https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git

And then TidyTDS:

https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds.git

This post may help:

[Using ActiveRecord for tables that aren't named as plurals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318725/using-activerecord-for-tables-that-arent-named-as-plurals/11319081#11319081)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you've always used ORM that generated the db from code and not the other way around then what you need might be [Linq to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) but you can also achieve this with many other ORMs.